# How to create variable html form based on keys in some other file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to update attributes about a particular person via an html form. Each html form, however, should be slightly different for each person. I have a file with a mapping from person -> form fields. How can I make an html form who fields are populated by a mapping in another file?

HTML, Javascript, or PHP solutions fine.

Comment: with javascript?

Comment: @sweaver2112 : javascript is fine

Comment: Post your code that you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create your Forms dynamically. You can use this library to create forms via json : https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform

It's very easy to use and has all the HTML form components.

Sample :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Getting started with JSON Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/deps/opt/bootstrap.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Getting started with JSON Form</h1>
    <form></form>
    <div id="res" class="alert"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/deps/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/deps/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/deps/opt/jsv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/lib/jsonform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('form').jsonForm({
        schema: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
            title: 'Name',
            required: true
          },
          age: {
            type: 'number',
            title: 'Age'
          }
        },
        onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
          if (errors) {
            $('#res').html('<p>I beg your pardon?</p>');
          }
          else {
            $('#res').html('<p>Hello ' + values.name + '.' +
              (values.age ? '<br/>You are ' + values.age + '.' : '') +
              '</p>');
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - What is a recommended way to import this json schema from a  file ?

Comment: You can fetch the JSON from a file using an AJAX call and pass it to the function. jQuery AJAX example : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp